# Как заменить значение строки в массиве строк?

Tags: строки, kotlin, список, replace

Загружаю список строк `names`.

```
override fun onLoadSuccess(result: List<TransactionListItem>, names: List<String>) {
    data = result
    nameSuggestions = names
    contract.dataSetChanged()
}
```

Но суть в том, что в `names` мне приходят строки типа:

```
Electronics &amp; Software
```

Но мне вместо `&amp;` нужно отобразить просто `&`.
Я так понимаю можно это сделать с помощью функкции расширения `replace` но она применяется к строке, а мне необходимо для всего списка применить данное правило.

**UPD:**

Переменная для которой хочу применить изменения

```
var nameSuggestions: List<String> = emptyList()
    private set
```

и в месте где сэчу значения сейчас делаю следующим образом:

```
override fun onLoadSuccess(result: List<TransactionContentViewModel>, names: List<String>) {
    data = result
    nameSuggestions = names.map {
        it.replace("&amp;", "&")
    }
    contract.dataSetChanged()
}
```

Но если обращаюсь после из фрагмента к переменной `nameSuggestions` всё равно получаю значения с `Electronics &amp; Software`
Код во фрагменте:

```
private fun updateAutoCompleteList() {
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(activity ?: return,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, searchTransactionsPresenter.nameSuggestions)
    searchInputView?.setAdapter(adapter)
}
```

Comment: `val replaced = names.map { it.replace("amp", "") }` вот так вроде должно сработать

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov да, пишу что то подобное https://pl.kotl.in/r3faVWCpJ и работает как надо, но увы когда обращаюсь к своей переменной из фрагмента, изменения эти не применяются должным образом, видимо проблема в чём то другом, но ответ можно оформить. У меня проблема в другом.

Comment: А к какой переменной Вы обращаетесь? names или namesSuggestions?

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov обновил вопрос(UPD). Думаю так будет более понятно.

Comment: это что-то ну оооочень странное:)